# Tkinter entry in (python) doesn't get the value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am new to tkinter, my code's main menu entry functions work properly but the add project entry function doesn't work, I want to get addprojects entry value to a variable for further code expantion. But I am stuck in here searching every coner for a solution. No idea why only one functions entry work and others doesn't when both are same.
here is my full code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

global YourChoice
global ProjectsDetails
global AvWorkers

YourChoice = 0
ProjectsDetails = []
AvWorkers = 100

def WinSelect():
    global YourChoice
    print(YourChoice)
    if(YourChoice == 1):
        addProject()

    #Remove Completed Project - function call.
    elif(YourChoice == 2):
        rProject()

    #Add new workers.
    elif(YourChoice == 3):
        AddWorkers()

    #Update Project Details.
    if(YourChoice == 4):
        UpProject()

    #Project Statistics.
    if(YourChoice == 5):
        pStats()

    #Exit the program
    elif(YourChoice == 6):
        exit()

def addProject():
    addproject = Tk()
    addproject.geometry("700x400")
    addproject.title("Add a new project")
    
    label1 = Label(addproject, text="XYZ Company", font=("arial",20,"bold", "italic")).pack()
    label2 = Label(addproject, text="Add a new project", font=("arial",16)).pack()
    label3 = Label(addproject, text="Project Code          -     **Enter '0' to Project Code to exit.", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=100)
    label4 = Label(addproject, text="Clients Name         -", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=130)
    label5 = Label(addproject, text="Start date              -", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=160)
    label6 = Label(addproject, text="Expected end date -", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=190)
    label7 = Label(addproject, text="Number of workers -", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=220)
    label8 = Label(addproject, text="Project status        -", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=250)

    pc = IntVar()
    cn = StringVar()
    sd = StringVar()
    ed = StringVar()
    nw = IntVar()
    ps = StringVar()

    def submitb():
        ProjectCode = pc.get()
        print(ProjectCode)

    entry1 = Entry(addproject, textvariable = pc)
    entry1.place(x=525,y=100)
    entry2 = Entry(addproject, textvariable = cn)
    entry2.place(x=525,y=130)
    entry3 = Entry(addproject, textvariable = sd)
    entry3.place(x=525,y=160)
    entry4 = Entry(addproject, textvariable = ed)
    entry4.place(x=525,y=190)
    entry5 = Entry(addproject, textvariable = nw)
    entry5.place(x=525,y=220)
    entry6 = Entry(addproject, textvariable = ps)
    entry6.place(x=525,y=250)

    submit = Button(addproject, text="Submit Data", font=("arial",8), command=submitb).place(x=585,y=320)

def mainMenu():

    mainmenu = Tk()
    mainmenu.geometry("700x400")
    mainmenu.title("Main Menu")

    label1 = Label(mainmenu, text="XYZ Company", font=("arial",20,"bold", "italic")).pack()
    label2 = Label(mainmenu, text="Main Menu", font=("arial",16)).pack()
    label3 = Label(mainmenu, text="1. Add a new project to existing projects.", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=100)
    label4 = Label(mainmenu, text="2. Remove a completed project from existing projects.", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=130)
    label5 = Label(mainmenu, text="3. Add new workers to available workers group.", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=160)
    label6 = Label(mainmenu, text="4. Update details on ongoing projects.", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=190)
    label7 = Label(mainmenu, text="5. Project Statistics", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=220)
    label8 = Label(mainmenu, text="6. Exit", font=("arial",10)).place(x=50,y=250)

    yc = IntVar()

    def submitb():
        global YourChoice
        YourChoice = yc.get()
        WinSelect()

    entry1 = Entry(mainmenu, textvariable = yc).place(x=525,y=280)

    submit = Button(mainmenu, text="Submit Data", font=("arial",8), command=submitb).place(x=585,y=320)

mainMenu()

mainloop()
```

Tried everything, want to asign entry functions value to a variable

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post traceback?

Comment: I didn't get any errors. However, I Was able to fix the code, The problem was using Tk() more than twice in the wrong way. Thank You 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a bit difficult to understand, but I can give you a few pointers.

You are using more than one instance of `Tk()` which may cause problems. [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged/69062053#69062053)

Both the function that creates the addproject window and the Tk instance it creates are called `addproject`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you

It was a problem with using Tk() more than twice.
Thank you very much.